# Unexpected inconsistency

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu today and after repartitioning a part of the drive SDA3, mounting it, and rebooting I got an error message saying.

```
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 117081344 blocks
The physical size of the device is 104857600 blocks
Superblock or partition table is likely to be corrupt!
/dev/sda2: unexpected inconsistency; run fsck manually.
Fsck exited with status code 4
```

After I ran fsck /dev/sda2 I only got the same message and an abort with y prompt, meaning fsck fixed nothing.

What can I do to solve this?

Note:
I am running windows on a nvme ssd
and Ubuntu on a sata ssd.

Im doing the Linux from scratch book.

I skipped a couple things on the code part, I think they weren’t needed to explain the issue.

Comment: What commands did you use to change the drive?

Comment: Did you fsck the correct drive? You mention sda3 in your question but seem to have trouble with sda2. sda3 is a partition, you can resize it, change the filesystem on it or delete it. You cannot repartition a part of it. sda however refers to the whole drive which can contain none, one or more partitions. Can you clarify what you think you did and how you did it.

Comment: @David is used cfdisk, i had a sda1 for IFE sda2 for filesystem and resized sda2 to have free space wich i used to create sda3 for filesystem also.

Comment: @PonJar  i had a sda1 for IFE sda2 for filesystem and resized sda2 to have free space wich i used to create sda3 for filesystem also, is ran fsck on all three partitions just to be sure and all returned abort instead of a solution.

Comment: update: my drive only had ubuntu on it and a couple packages i downloaded, so i pluged my ISO wiped everything and did a fresh install. :p